# Create KML file with linestring and placemarks

Tags: xml, google-maps, kml

I am building a KML file using an app that I have built.  Right now I have it nicely drawing a linestring on the map. But, now I want to add a few placemarks inside the same KML file.  When trying to do this it will show either the line string or the place mark, but not both.

How can I do this inside a KML file?

What I currently use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xsi:schemaLocation="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1 http://earth.google.com/kml2.1.xsd" xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Placemark>
    <name>My Name</name>
    <Style>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>FF0000FF</color>
            <width>3.0</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <LineString>
      <extrude>false</extrude>
      <tessellate>true</tessellate>
      <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
      <coordinates>A Ton of coordinates go here</coordinates>
    </LineString>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I have to place all of the placemarks into a `<Folder>` in order to have multiple placemarks show, then it worked.

Comment: Are you aware that you are using the old 2.1 namespaces in your kml? See:"http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html

Comment: @NicHubbard: I am working on something similar. Can you please show me the KML or the Java code for how to get a line between two points. What I would like is to get markers of some kind on those points as well. Thanks in advance! :)